# Cypress - way to make contains() work in case-insensitive way

Tags: cypress

I have a project that doesn't capitalize on level of HTML and values in HTML have inconsistent capitalization.

Is there any way how to force Cypress to match text if I use only lower-case strings as arguments to contains() function?

Answer (score 63):

As of [4.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#4-0-0), Cypress offers [`matchCase`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Case-Sensitivity) option with `contains`...

`cy.get('div').contains('capital sentence', { matchCase: false })`

Answer (score 15):

Cypress contains methods already have such feature. You can just pass the `matchCase` as options argument and cypress will handle case sensistive/insensitive conditions. Below code snippet will help you.
If you like the answer, please like the answer and give vote up.

```
it('this will pass', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io');
    cy.contains('commands drive your tests', {matchCase: false})
  });

  it('this will fail', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io');
    cy.contains('commands drive your tests', {matchCase: true})
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

`contains()` can take a regular expression, for which you can specify case-insensitive matching with the `i` flag:

Other answers already mention this, but this might be the easiest way to use it:

```
cy.get('.some-selector').contains(/match cAse-InSENsitiVE/i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a case-insensitive regex to the contains command, although using regex you need to be careful to escape any special regex characters,
see this [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

```js
const escapeRegExp = (string) => {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

const expected = 'mYtEXTtO*tEST?';
const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(expected), 'i');

cy.contains(regex);
cy.contains('MySelector', regex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex.

`cy.get("#whatever").its("something").should("match", "[your regex here]")`

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has [lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_.html) included. So, this is my current workaround for non case sensitive text matching, until [Cypress includes this feature for cy.contains()](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2785)

```js
cy.get('p.heading').then( $headings => {
  let texts = $headings.map( (_, el) => (Cypress._.toUpper(el.textContent)));

  expect(texts.get()).to.include('INCONSISTENT CAPITALIZED TITLE 1');

  //If you have more to match
  expect(texts.get()).to.include('INCONSISTENT CAPITALIZED TITLE 2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Cypress 10 you can use this override to make contain not match case by default

```
    // set match case to default false
    Cypress.Commands.overwrite('contains', (originalFn, subject, value, options) => {
      const matchCase = options?.matchCase || false;
      return originalFn(subject, value, { ...options, matchCase });
    });
```